# Typescript intersection fails on list for... loop

Tags: typescript, loops, intersection

TLDR: [Typescript Playground SSCCE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0BiBXMwYF4YAoBuAhgDYD8AXDAN4zwC2BAlqRdAE4NgDmMAPjGCiJEA3DABGBViyjsuMAL4BKLAD4qAKBgxW8KClZhh6+UfWhIseHnhgoECgFEAHgjAATeG4DiAYWIPrWwBtAF0sGFCjADMQVlxzaBpA2BAopJs7ZUpNOEQoVHQcKwyAOljOAjAGAC94VkUjLQY0ouSSgihXD0QsnK0YuJwE2A6u+HgYVPTbds6bboherWXc5DRgHFH58Ya+hRz5Y3V1AHoTmABJWzqwYhgAFQBPAAdEdSgXiecxtwBBOfc43CAQy-zGEwAZDAAOoMKAACwAQpIjB9XjBvttvH4iCDbOFfP5kjAodktFtAYhyBiXFiwdt4JEcuVKjU6tTCbjkkEAOQsqq1Vg8sJQ2EI5GsIwmdQcBCsKIEYATMVIyQaLQSKQwNgcThS45nB6fCAwKKsEC0GCcEAgThEeAEZ4MCAy67yxUTTl42BkmAUhbU730ylMrT8tmsakAeVYFQFdX1rrlCqVGOSwe66po9CY1J1cj4AiEjXEBGqeZkusTsrqKYmMbjEazdEYzG1lYL-EEIhyMRAFdkeqOyyAA)

I'm having trouble getting the code to compile when the intersecting fields contain lists.

Really it's an intersection within an intersection, but it works as expected when the field is not a list (no error on `testFunc(event.organizer)`).

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ email?: string | null | undefined; }' is not assignable 
  to parameter of type '{ email?: string | null | undefined; bar: string; }'.

Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ email?: string | null | undefined; }'
  but required in type '{ email?: string | null | undefined; bar: string; }'.

10      testFunc(attendee);
                 ~~~~~~~~
```

```js
const testFunc = (val?: { email?: string | null; bar: string }) => {
  return;
};

const events: ExtendedGCalEvent[] = [];
for (const event of events) {
  testFunc(event.organizer);
  if (event.attendees) {
    for (const attendee of event.attendees) {
      testFunc(attendee);
    }
  }
}

// Internal Types
type ExtendedAttendee = EventAttendee & WithBar;
type ExtendedGCalEvent = GCalEvent & {
  attendees?: ExtendedAttendee[];
  organizer?: GCalEvent['organizer'] & WithBar;
};
interface WithBar {
  bar: string;
}

// Types from googleapis
interface GCalEvent {
  attendees?: EventAttendee[];
  organizer?: Organizer;
}

interface EventAttendee {
  email?: string | null;
  baz?: string;
}

interface Organizer {
  email?: string | null;
  foo?: string;
}
```

Take note of the inferred types in the inner `for` loop on `attendee : EventAttendee` and `myEvent.attendees : EventAttendee[] & ExtendedAttendee[]`, this is where the information seems to get lost.

Even if one were to change `ExtendedGCalEvent.attendees` to something random like `string` you see the same error.

It compiles if you coerce it like so: `for (const attendee of event.attendees as ExtendedGCalAttendee[]) {...}`

Comment: Okay, this is weird behavior in the `for..of` loop.  It *might* be a bug in TypeScript; I'll file something and get back to you.  I think in your case though I'd suggest extending interfaces like `interface ExtendedAttendee extends EventAttendee, WithBar { }` and `interface ExtendedOrganizer extends Organizer, WithBar { }` and `interface ExtendedGCalEvent extends GCalEvent { attendees?: ExtendedAttendee[]; organizer?: ExtendedOrganizer }` instead of using intersections.  If I hear back from my filed bug I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. I was able to get the compiler to stop complaining when I changed it to `WithBar { bar?: string }` (same as `bar: string | undefined` I think?). Turns out that was also the correct structure I needed in my model, and not just a hack, so it works out.

Comment: Your `extends` suggestion works nicely too. Thanks!